# Preciso de dois cliques para ativar função Jquey

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Olá,
estou aprendendo a trabalhar com requisições em AJAX/JSON, e me deparei com um problema (que acho que te mais a ver com Jquery, mas adicionei as tags PHP e AJAX, pois nunca se sabe).
vamos lá;

1. ao acessar a página no navegador, será feita uma requisição AJAX a um arquivo PHP que acessar o BD e gerar um JSON. Este contém os items que vão compor os INPUTS RADIOS do meu form.
2. O primeiro INPUT do FORM contem a propriedade CHECKED.
3. O meu Arquivo javascipt.js tem uma segunda função contida no **"$(document).ready"**. Esta função faz a requisição de acordo com o INPUT selecionado. O **problema** é que para que este evento seja disparado eu preciso dar 2 cliques. Gostaria que as informações já fossem mostradas assim que carregadas (essa foi a intenção de atribuir CHECKED ao primeiro INPUT).

Alguém poderia ajudar?
Desde já, obrigado.

Função que carrega os dados através da requisição AJAX:

```
//função pra carregar inputs
function carregarItens() {
  var radios = "";

  $.ajax({
    url: "primeira.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data[0].erro) {
        $("h1").html(data[0].erro);
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          radios += '<input id="teste" type="radio" name="noticia"';
          radios += 'value="' + data[i].id;
          radios += '"/>' + data[i].produto + '</br>';
        }
        $('form').html(radios);
        $('input:first').prop('checked', true);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Código responsável em alterar o conteúdo conforme o `input` selecionado:

```
//consulta dinamica
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {**

      var noticia = $(this).val();
      var itens = "";

      $.ajax({
        url: "processa.php",
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          noticia: noticia
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data[0].erro) {
            $("#resultado").html(data[0].erro);
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              itens += "<div>";
              itens += "<p>" + data[i].id + "</p>";
              itens += "<p>" + data[i].produto + "</p>";
              itens += "<p>" + data[i].valor + "</p>";
              itens += "</div>";
            }
            $("#resultado").html(itens);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Estrutura do arquivo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teste Sem refresh</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="carregarItens()">
  <h1>Busca sem refresh</h1>
  <h2></h2>
  <form></form>
  </br>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer carregar as informações assim que você selecionar um radio button certo?

Comment: Não seria porquê você precisa capturar o evento `change` tanto do `form` como do `input`? Acredito que apenas do `input` seja suficiente.

Comment: usa o `dblclick(function(){});`

Comment: Acho que a tag PHP deveria ser removida.

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar no final do `$(document).ready`:

```
$('form input[type="radio"]:first').trigger('change');
```

E só é preciso atribuir change aos inputs, não precisa pro form.

A função fica assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

      var noticia = $(this).val();
        var itens = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: "processa.php",
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                noticia: noticia
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data[0].erro) {
                    $("#resultado").html(data[0].erro);
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        itens += "<div>";
                        itens += "<p>" + data[i].id + "</p>";
                        itens += "<p>" + data[i].produto + "</p>";
                        itens += "<p>" + data[i].valor + "</p>";
                        itens += "</div>";
                    }
                    $("#resultado").html(itens);
                }
            }
        });
    });


/////
    $('form input[type="radio"]:first').trigger('change');

});
```